# Loop through Array and return result into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, hp-service-manager

I have this array:

```
var shareholders = [“name1”, “name2”, “name3”];
```

This is function from HPSM that is fetching data from that array:

```
function getShareholders(RECORD)
 {
  var fShareholder = new SCFile("device");
  var rc = fShareholder.doSelect("logical.name=\"" + RECORD + "\"");
  if (rc == RC_SUCCESS)
  {
    print(fShareholder.shareholder_contacts);
    return fShareholder.sharholder_contacts;
    }
 return null;
}
```

It returns them in array form but I need it to fetch one by one:

```
var users = new Array();
users[0] = “name1”
users[1] = “name2”
….
```

I have tried them to loop through for loop but without success.

Comment: when you are not doing anything with array just use same variable there..

Comment: I need to create HTML Template for sending an e-mail to "shareholders" which are stored into "device" table. Shareholders are stored into an array of strings (characters) and I am fetching them from there to another part of the application so I can send an e-mail.

Comment: @DinoFilipovic, it is working my solution for you ?

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, yes, thank you. It worked. :) I have combined that with HPSM tools features and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `forEach` function, which accepts a `callback` function.

`forEach` method executes a provided function once for each array element.

Syntax:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {

}[, thisArg]);
```

```js
var shareholders = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
var users=new Array();
shareholders.forEach(function(item,i){
  users[i]=item;
});
console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function?

```
var shareholders = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
var users = shareholders.map(function (user){
  return user; // Do transformation here
});
console.log(users);
```

Comment: map method isn't a good choice in this situation. Usually it's used when you have to modify structure of array items.

Comment: I wouldn't judge wether or not it is a good choice since it is unclear to me what the OP is actually asking. If he want's to simply copy an array (and not modify it), something like `shareholders.slice(0);` would be faster or `Array.from(shareholders);` would be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to fetch the array items one by one, you can use Iterator here like this:

```
function makeIterator(array) {
    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
       next: function() {
           return nextIndex < array.length ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
               {done: true};
       }
    };
}
```

Once initialized, the next() method can be called to access key-value pairs from the object in turn:

```
var it = makeIterator([“name1”, “name2”, “name3”];);
console.log(it.next().value); // 'name1'
console.log(it.next().value); // 'name2'
console.log(it.next().value); // 'name3'
console.log(it.next().done);  // true
```

you can check the details here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators. (This example is also from the link.)

Answer (score 1):

Use es6 deconstruction to spread the `Array shareholders`. Such as

let [user1, user2] = shareholders;// user1 equals shareholders[0] user2 equals shareholders[1].